# join with JDatabase doesn't work

Tags: php, sql, joomla

I'm beginner with Joomla! and i'm trying to get informations from my database, but it doesn't work, Joomla! display a blank page, which means there is an execution error with my PHP code.

Here is the code of my request :

```
$query
->select($db->quoteName(array('orders.order_id', 'user.first_name', 'user.last_name')))
->from($db->quoteName('#__orders', 'orders'))
->join('LEFT', $db->quoteName('#__userinfos', 'user').' ON ('.$db->quoteName('orders.user_id').' = '.$db-quoteName('user.user_id') .')')
->where($db->quoteName('address_type').' = '.$db->quote('BT'));
```

I know the error comes from the join function, because when i comment it, there is no error

Here is the SQL request i want to call

```
SELECT orders.order_id, users.first_name, users.last_name 
FROM prefix_orders orders LEFT JOIN prefix_userinfos users
ON orders.ser_id = users.user_id
WHERE address_type = 'BT'");
```

thanks

Comment: `('#__orders', 'orders')` << what's the second parameter for?

Comment: it's just an alias
instead to have to write #__orders.user_id, i just have to write orders.user_id

Comment: can you post the code for your whole query, right from the very start `$db =` to the end. As it might not be the query itself causing the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a syntax error in the last quote of the join method:

```
 $db-quoteName('user.user_id')
```

instead of

```
$db->quoteName('user.user_id')
```

Illusive one, I would say.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify where the column 'address_type' comes from (users or orders table), otherwise mysql can't find it in your query.